# Why do I get an syntax error in IE11 when trying to generate a GOJS diagram

Tags: internet-explorer-11, gojs

I can generate the diagram in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Microsoft Edge but not in IE11.  When I look at the console, it tells me that there are two issues:

1.) 'init' is undefined
2.) Syntax error

In the initialization I do the following:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gojs/release/go.js"></script>
<script src="/js/GenerateMap.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        init();
    });
</script>
```

Inside GenerateMap.js I have the following:

```
function init() {
var newString = document.getElementById("valueFromServer").value;
var GO = go.GraphObject.make;
....}
```

And for the Syntax error it tells me that it's at line 13. The line containing ").":

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("",
    GO(go.Node, "Auto",
        // the entire node will have a light-blue background
        { resizable: false, width: 130, height: 80, background: "transparent" },
        { click: function (e, node) { var data = node.data; clicknode(data.key);} },
        GO(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", { fill: "white" },
            new go.Binding("fill", "isSelected", function (sel) {
                if (sel) return "lightgoldenrodyellow"; else return "white";
            }).ofObject("").makeTwoWay()),
        GO(go.TextBlock, "Default Text",
            { stroke: "grey", font: "11px sans-serif", maxLines: 4, overflow: go.TextBlock.OverflowEllipsis },
            new go.Binding("text", "name"),
        ),
        new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse)
    ));
```

Why would these issues only be with IE11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        { stroke: "grey", font: "11px sans-serif", maxLines: 4, overflow: go.TextBlock.OverflowEllipsis },
        new go.Binding("text", "name"),
```

The issue is related to the above code, at the end of the Binding method, there have an extra ',' symbol, try to remove it.

The following code should be works well, try to use it.

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("",
    GO(go.Node, "Auto",
        // the entire node will have a light-blue background
        { resizable: false, width: 130, height: 80, background: "transparent" },
        { click: function (e, node) { var data = node.data; clicknode(data.key);} },
        GO(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", { fill: "white" },
            new go.Binding("fill", "isSelected", function (sel) {
                if (sel) return "lightgoldenrodyellow"; else return "white";
            }).ofObject("").makeTwoWay()),
        GO(go.TextBlock, "Default Text",
            { stroke: "grey", font: "11px sans-serif", maxLines: 4, overflow: go.TextBlock.OverflowEllipsis },
            new go.Binding("text", "name")
        ),
        new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse)
    ));
```

Comment: That was it, THANK YOU!!!!  I found two other places I did the same thing.  I fixed it and the map is generated in IE11.